# Traversing a Hash Recursively in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm having a problem with this function that traverses a Hash. The Hash may contain an Array of Hashes. I want the method to search for an id and then return just the nested hash it finds.

It seems to work for the traversal, but it returns the original value passed in.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'ruby-debug'

def find_by_id(node, find_this="")
  if node.is_a?(Hash)
    node.each do |k,v|
      if v.is_a?(Array)
        v.each do |elm|
          if elm["_id"] == find_this && !find_this.empty?
            return elm      # THIS IS WHAT I WANT!
          else
            find_by_id(elm, find_this)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

x = {"name" => "first", "_id"=>'4c96a9a56f831b0eb9000005', "items"=>["name" => "second", "_id"=>'4c96a9af6f831b0eb9000009', "others"=>[{"name" => "third", "_id"=>'4c96a9af6f831b0eb9000007'}, {"name" => "fourth", "_id"=>'4c96a9af6f831b0eb9000008'}] ] }

find_by_id(x, '4c96a9af6f831b0eb9000008')
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you invoke `find_by_id` recursively, you're not doing anything with the return value. You need to check whether it found something and if so return that, i.e.:

```
result = find_by_id(elm, find_this)
return result if result
```

You also need to return `nil` at the end of the method (after the each loop), so it returns `nil` if nothing was found. If you don't, it'll return the return value of `each` which is the hash that you iterated over.

Edit:

Here's the full code with the changes I outlined:

```
def find_by_id(node, find_this="")
  if node.is_a?(Hash)
    node.each do |k,v|
      if v.is_a?(Array)
        v.each do |elm|
          if elm["_id"] == find_this && !find_this.empty?
            return elm      # THIS IS WHAT I WANT!
          else
            result = find_by_id(elm, find_this)
            return result if result
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
  # Return nil if no match was found
  nil
end
```

Edit2:

An alternative approach, that I find cleaner, is to separate the logic for iterating the structure from the logic for finding the element with the right id:

```
def dfs(hsh, &blk)
  return enum_for(:dfs, hsh) unless blk

  yield hsh
  hsh.each do |k,v|
    if v.is_a? Array
      v.each do |elm|
        dfs(elm, &blk)
      end
    end
  end
end

def find_by_id(hsh, search_for)
  dfs(hsh).find {|node| node["_id"] == search_for }
end
```

By making `dfs` return an `Enumerable` we can use the `Enumerable#find` method, which makes the code a bit simpler.

This also enables code reuse if you ever need to write another method that needs to iterate through the hash recursively, as you can just reuse the dfs method.

Comment: I tried that, it returns the wrong value. `return elm ` does get reached though when it is supposed to.

Comment: @Dex: Right. You also need to return nil if you don't find anything. Edited to add that.

Comment: I'd like to point out that it's not the recursion to blame, but  rather `each` operator, from inside of which last operator doesn't return its value from the original function.

Comment: Perhaps someone can post the full code? I'm still having issues.

Comment: @Dex: By just putting `nil` at the end of the method (right before the last `end`) it works for me.

Comment: Me too! Thanks, this was driving me nuts!

Comment: Elegant solution under "Edit2". I love the reusability. `dfs` means [depth-first search](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/algorithm-week-graph-depth), right?