# Ruby search for super nested key from json response

Tags: ruby, json

I have a terribly nested Json response.

```
[[{:test=>[{:id=>1, :b=>{id: '2'}}]}]]
```

There's more arrays than that but you get the idea.
Is there a way to recursively search through and find all the items that have a key I need?

I tried using this function [extract_list()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9119299/2719355) but it doesn't handle arrays well.

Comment: That JSON response is malformed. Mismatched brackets? (`[{id:1]}`) Key without value? (`{test,`) Uneven number of brackets and braces?

Comment: Edited example to make it less malformed and to have same key twice, since mentioned "find all the items that have a key I need".

Answer (score 1):

```
def nested_find(obj, needed_keys)
  return {} unless obj.is_a?(Array) || obj.is_a?(Hash)
  obj.inject({}) do |hash, val|
    if val.is_a?(Hash) && (tmp = needed_keys & val.keys).length > 0
      tmp.each { |key| hash[key] = val[key] }
    elsif val.is_a?(Array)
      hash.merge!(obj.map { |v| nested_find(v, needed_keys) }.reduce(:merge))
    end
    hash
  end
end
```

## Example

```
needed_keys = [:id, :another_key]
nested_find([ ['test', [{id:1}], [[another_key: 5]]]], needed_keys)
 # {:id=>1, :another_key=>5}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is not what I'd suggest, but just to give a brief alternative to the other solutions provided:

```
2.1.1 :001 > obj = [[{:test=>[{:id=>1, :b=>{id: '2'}}]}]] 
 => [[{:test=>[{:id=>1, :b=>{:id=>"2"}}]}]] 
2.1.1 :002 > key = :id
 => :id
2.1.1 :003 > obj.inspect.scan(/#{key.inspect}=>([^,}]*)[,}]/).flatten.map {|s| eval s}
 => [1, "2"]
```

Note: use of eval here is just for an example. It would fail/produce incorrect results on anything whose inspect value was not eval-able back to the same instance, and it can execute malicious code:

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write your own recursive handler. Assuming that you've already converted your JSON to a Ruby data structure (via JSON.load or whatnot):

```
def deep_find_value_with_key(data, desired_key)
  case data
  when Array
    data.each do |value|
      if found = deep_find_value_with_key value, desired_key
        return found
      end
    end
  when Hash
    if data.key?(desired_key)
      data[desired_key]
    else
      data.each do |key, val|
        if found = deep_find_value_with_key(val, desired_key)
          return found
        end
      end
    end
  end
  return nil
end
```

The general idea is that given a data structure, you check it for the key (if it's a hash) and return the matching value if found. Otherwise, you iterate it (if it's an Array or Hash) and perform the same check on each of it's children.

This will find the value for the first occurrence of the given key, or nil if the key doesn't exist in the tree. If you need to find *all* instances then it's slightly different  - you basically need to pass an array that will accumulate the values:

```
def deep_find_value_with_key(data, desired_key, hits = [])
  case data
  when Array
    data.each do |value|
      deep_find_value_with_key value, desired_key, hits
    end
  when Hash
    if data.key?(desired_key)
      hits << data[desired_key]
    else
      data.each do |key, val|
        deep_find_value_with_key(val, desired_key)
      end
    end
  end

  return hits
end
```

Comment: Hmm the all instances (or either) doesn't seem to work I tried `puts deep_find_value_with_key(data, :api).inspect`

Comment: I didn't test the code - it may need some tweaking. But the general idea is correct - you have to do a deep iteration of the data, checking keys every time you encounter a hash. You may need to do some legwork to make sure it works properly for your case.