# DFS traversal of a deeply nested hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I have seen this question [Traversing a Hash Recursively in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748744/traversing-a-hash-recursively-in-ruby)

However I am still not able to achieve this. Can anyone please help (also explain).

Input hash:

```
{"." => {"foo" => {"hello" => {}, "world" => {}}, "bar" => {}}}
```

I just need to traverse it and not search for anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all values are hashes, this would work:

```
hash = {"." => {"foo" => {"hello" => {}, "world" => {}}, "bar" => {}}}

def traverse(hash, depth = 0)
  hash.each do |key, value|
    puts "#{depth} #{key}"
    traverse(value, depth + 1)
  end
end

traverse(hash)
```

Output:

```
0 .
1 foo
2 hello
2 world
1 bar
```

Comment: this looks great. I was also interested in following its backtracking. But I think I can figure that out myself now that I have a good starting point. Thanks :)