# Finding depth of value in deeply nested hash

Tags: ruby, hash, nested, nested-loops

I have the following deeply nested ordered hash of ruby objects:

```
{
  #<Post:0x007f8a3dcc3980
  id: 1,
  title: "Title 1",
  created_at: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 05:49:27 EDT -04:00,
  updated_at: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 05:49:27 EDT -04:00>=>{
    #<Post:0x007f8a3dc735e8
    id: 7,
    title: "Title 1",
    created_at: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 05:49:31 EDT -04:00,
    updated_at: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 05:49:31 EDT -04:00>=>{},
    #<Post:0x007f8a3dc4bea8
    id: 5,
    title: "Title 2",
    created_at: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 05:49:31 EDT -04:00,
    updated_at: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 05:49:31 EDT -04:00>=>{},
    #<Post:0x007f8a3dc3b760
    id: 4,
    title: "Title 3",
    created_at: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 05:49:31 EDT -04:00,
    updated_at: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 05:49:31 EDT -04:00>=>{},
    #<Post:0x007f8a3bd68d60
    id: 3,
    title: "Title 4",
    created_at: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 05:49:31 EDT -04:00,
    updated_at: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 05:49:31 EDT -04:00>=>{},
    #<Post:0x007f8a3db63928
    id: 9,
    title: "Title 5",
    created_at: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 05:49:31 EDT -04:00,
    updated_at: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 05:49:31 EDT -04:00>=>{}
  },
  #<Post:0x007f8a3dcc2c88
  id: 10,
  title: "Title 2",
  created_at: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 05:49:27 EDT -04:00,
  updated_at: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 05:49:27 EDT -04:00>=>{},
  #<Post:0x007f8a3dcc2c88
  id: 13,
  title: "Title 3",
  created_at: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 05:49:27 EDT -04:00,
  updated_at: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 05:49:27 EDT -04:00>=>{},
  #<Post:0x007f8a3dcc2c88
  id: 18,
  title: "Title 4",
  created_at: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 05:49:27 EDT -04:00,
  updated_at: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 05:49:27 EDT -04:00>=>{
    #<Post:0x007f8a3dc83358
    id: 11,
    title: "Title 1",
    created_at: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 05:49:30 EDT -04:00,
    updated_at: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 05:49:30 EDT -04:00>=>{
      #<Post:0x007f8a3c21c708
      id: 20,
      title: "Title 1",
      created_at: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 05:49:30 EDT -04:00,
      updated_at: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 05:49:30 EDT -04:00>=>{
        #<Post:0x007f8a3c21c708
        id: 24,
        title: "Title 1",
        created_at: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 05:49:30 EDT -04:00,
        updated_at: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 05:49:30 EDT -04:00>=>{},
      },
    },
  },
  #<Post:0x007f8a3c21c708
  id: 12,
  title: "Title 5",
  created_at: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 05:49:30 EDT -04:00,
  updated_at: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 05:49:30 EDT -04:00>=>{},
  #<Post:0x007f8a3c216f38
  id: 16,
  title: "Title 6",
  created_at: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 05:49:30 EDT -04:00,
  updated_at: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 05:49:30 EDT -04:00>=>{},
  #<Post:0x007f8a3bd7ab28
  id: 17,
  title: "Title 7",
  created_at: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 05:49:30 EDT -04:00,
  updated_at: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 05:49:30 EDT -04:00>=>{}
}
```

What I'm trying to do is a build a flat list of these objects with an some formatting that indicates the depth of each object in the hash. I.e:

```
Title 1
- Title 1
- Title 2
- Title 3
- Title 4
- Title 5
Title 2
Title 3
Title 4
- Title 1
-- Title 1
--- Title 1
Title 5
Title 6
Title 7
```

I've tried a function that iterates over each level of the hash and increases a variable for each depth it descends. The problem is that it ends up like this:

```
Title 1
- Title 1
- Title 2
- Title 3
- Title 4
- Title 5
- Title 2
- Title 3
- Title 4
-- Title 1
--- Title 1
---- Title 1
---- Title 5
---- Title 6
---- Title 7
```

It would be far better if I could determine the depth of each individual object in the hash. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

**Updated with current method:**

```
  def iterate_hash(hash)
    hash.each do |hash|
      "#{dash_level} #{hash[0][:name]}",
      hash[0][:id]
      next if hash[1].blank?
      dash_level = dash_level + '-'
      iterate_hash(hash[1])
    end
  end
```

Comment: Seems like you implemented [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), but you will need [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). Please post your code, you probably only need a few minor changes.

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666422/dfs-traversal-of-a-deeply-nested-hash